# set jinja2 url_for as an href in getJSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2, getjson

I am working inside a jquery, getJSON callback function using flask as my web framework.
I am trying to set the link desination for a dynamically created dom element.  I want to set it to the jinja2 code for url_for.  So, I would like to do something like this:

```
a.href ="{{ url_for('write_response', id=".concat(data.libArticles[i].id.toString(), ") }}");
```

I have had the worst time doing this.  First, it would not recognize the "{{" and "}}" strings, removing them, opening quotes and doing other weird stuff because of those characters.  Finally, by doing this:

```
var url1 = "{url_for('write_response', id=".concat(data.libArticles[i].id.toString(),")}");
var url2 ="{".concat(url1, "}");
a.href = url2;
```

it finally accepted the string with two instances of "{", so it accepted "{{somethig}}"

This still did not work and instead, when the link is clicked, it redirects to the following and fails :

http://localhost:5000/write_response/%7B%7Burl_for('write_response',%20id=3)%7D%7D

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing up your python and javascript. Your first attempt failed, because your trying to execute javascript inside python. What's actually happening is everything, including the ".concat is being treated as the value for your id. Your second attempt is even more confused.

It's worth remembering that the python code gets executed on the server and then sent to the browser, the javascript gets executed after the fact in the browser. So the python/jinja code can't possibly know about the value of a javascript variable.

I think you should be able to do something like the following to get it to work:

```
var url = "{{ url_for('write_response') }}";
var id = encodeURIComponent(data.libArticles[i].id.toString());
url += '?id='+id;
```

Everything inside the set of {{ }} is considered jinja code, seperate from whatever is going on around it in the file. this should translate into the following in the browser:

```
var url = "/write-response";
var id = encodeURIComponent(data.libArticles[i].id.toString());
url += '?id='+id;
```

which should get you something like /write-response?id=12345
The encodeURLComponent(..) call just makes sure the value is url safe.